# Not able to run/execute MySQL Triggers

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am creating Trigger into Mysql Workbanch , but not able to create the trigger.
Can Anyone Help me For This.

```
DELIMITER $$
create TRIGGER Insert_Test
After Delete ON Test
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 START TRANSACTION;
 DECLARE v_ID    INT; 
 DECLARE v_Error TINYINT; 
 DECLARE v_AgentID INT;
 SELECT  v_Error = 0; 

 v_ID=Old.id;
   BEGIN  
   DELETE Test2 WHERE id = SELECT id FROM Test where id=v_ID;
   Rollback;
   SET v_Error = 1; 
   END  
 IF v_Error = 0;   
THEN  
COMMIT;  
ELSEIF   
v_Error = 1;   
THEN  
ROLLBACK;  
END IF;  
END     
DELIMITER ;
```

**Sql server Trigger**

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_DelRecordTypeID] ON [dbo].[luRecordType] FOR DELETE  
 AS  
SET NOCOUNT ON  
BEGIN TRANSACTION  
    DECLARE @ID INT, @GroupTypeID INT, @Error BIT, @Msg VARCHAR(500)  
    SELECT  @Error = 0  
    SELECT  @ID = RecordTypeID FROM deleted   
    SELECT  @GroupTypeID = 30  
    IF EXISTS ( SELECT  g.GroupID  
                FROM    luGroup g,  
                        [luGroupDetail] gd  
                WHERE   g.[GroupID] = gd.[GroupID]  
                        AND g.[GroupTypeID] = @GroupTypeID  
                        AND gd.[MemberID] = @ID )   
        BEGIN  
          DELETE [agAgent] WHERE [AgentID] = (SELECT TOP 1 AgentID FROM agAgentPayType)   
          Rollback transaction   
          SET @Error = 1  
        END       
    IF @Error = 0   
        BEGIN  
            COMMIT TRANSACTION  
        END  
    ELSE   
        IF @Error = 1   
            BEGIN  
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION  
            END
```

This trigger which i am trying to achieve into mysql workbanch, please check
I shall Be thankful,
Thanks
Aman

Comment: ok, Thanks for reply , then please correct me on this (v_ID=Old.id).

Comment: syntax errors here - 1) all declares must appear before any other statement 2) assignations need to be SET AND there is no OLD. record on an insert trigger

Comment: It might help if you stated what you are trying to do because this trigger looks a mess.

Comment: Can you add the sql  trigger as text to the question please.

Comment: @P.Salmon , please check Now, I added sql server Trigger as Text